# how to count occurrence of each unique value in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, count

I have large pandas dataframe, I would like to count the occurrence of each unique value in it, I try following but it takes to much time and memory usage. How can I do it in a pythonic way?

```
pack=[]
for index,row in packets.iterrows ():
    pack.extend(pd.Series(row).dropna().values.tolist())

unique, count= np.unique(pack, return_counts=True)
counts= np.asarray((unique, count))
```

Comment: How about `packets.value_counts()`?

Comment: Also, why are you creating the `pack` list and not doing anything with it?

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: Uh, I thought it was a series. Do you want to find the count of every single value in every column together? Just do `u,c = np.unique(packets.values.ravel(), return_counts=True)`

Comment: The result is `(array([ 58.,  59.,  62., ...,  nan,  nan,  nan]), array([120,   3,   5, ...,   1,   1,   1], dtype=int64))` which is not the count of each unique value in the whole dataframe

Comment: `pd.Series(packets.values.ravel()).dropna().value_counts()` then?

Comment: Please convert your comment to answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you want to compute value counts across *all columns*. You can flatten it to a series, drop NaNs, and call `value_counts`. Here's a sample -

```
df

     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  1.0  NaN
2  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  4.0
4  5.0  NaN
5  NaN  4.0
6  NaN  5.0
```

```
pd.Series(df.values.ravel()).dropna().value_counts()

5.0    2
4.0    2
3.0    2
1.0    2
dtype: int64
```

Another method is with `np.unique` -

```
u, c = np.unique(pd.Series(df.values.ravel()).dropna().values, return_counts=True)
pd.Series(c, index=u)

1.0    2
3.0    2
4.0    2
5.0    2
dtype: int64
```

Note that the first method sorts results in descending order of counts, while the latter does not.